# Steam loading inventory trying until its loaded

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is the code i wrote so far:

```html
<?php
do {
    //If this isn't the first time in the loop, pause for a second to prevent spamming their servers
    if(isset($statusCode)){
        sleep(1);
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198258195397/inventory/json/730/2");
    //The curl request should return the body of the text
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Apparently the URL provided initially returns with a 3XX response, this option follows the redirection.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $steamData = curl_exec($ch);

    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //Repeat this command until we get a successful request
    //Note that this is slightly naive - Any 2XX should be deemed successful.
} while ($statusCode !== 200);

//$steamData = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198258195397/inventory/json/730/2");
$data = json_decode($steamData, true);
$items = $data['rgDescriptions'];
foreach($items as $key => $item){
  $market_hash_name = $item["market_hash_name"];
  $market_hash_name = htmlentities($market_hash_name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $sql = "SELECT price FROM itemprice WHERE market_hash_name='".$market_hash_name."'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $itemprice = "-";
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
  {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
    if($row['price']>0.02){
     $itemprice = $row['price'];
     $itemprice = floatval($itemprice);
     $itemprice = $itemprice*1.05;
     $itemprice = round($itemprice, 3);
    }else{
     $itemprice = 0;
    }
   }
  }
        echo '<div class="items"><center><img src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/' . $item["icon_url"] . '" height="192" width="256"></center><div><center><h5 style="color:#'.$item["name_color"].'">'.$item["market_name"].' - <strong><b><a style="color:green">$'.$itemprice.'</a></b></strong></h5></center></div></div>';
} 
?>
```

So sometimes its just loading and after around 20sec it stops the chrome giving me an error like i dont have internet connection, and i cant open any page on the site for 1min.But after that everything is okay...Does anybody know another alternative to get the inv? 
here is a ss of the output on the site: https://gyazo.com/80e9d1cf3e6dd0ae151a9f85cc1e0cf9